# config Realm on Tomcat 6, Oracle 11g exception

Tags: oracle, tomcat, jbpm, realm

I need to config realm on tomcat 6 for oracle 11g to work for jBPM workflow.

So I created a file: `jbpm-console.xml` under Catalina/localhost like this:

```
<Context>
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" 
     driverName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
     connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myip:1524:mydb"
     connectionName="jbpm" 
     connectionPassword="jbpm"
     userTable="JBPM_ID_USER u, JBPM_ID_MEMBERSHIP m, JBPM_ID_GROUP g" 
     userNameCol="g.TYPE_ = 'security-role' AND m.GROUP_ = g.ID_ AND m.USER_ = u.ID_ AND u.NAME_" 
     userCredCol="DISTINCT u.PASSWORD_"
     userRoleTable="JBPM_ID_USER u, JBPM_ID_MEMBERSHIP m, JBPM_ID_GROUP g" 
     roleNameCol="g.NAME_" ></Realm>
</Context>
```

When I try to log in `jBPM` I get the exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception performing authentication
java.sql.SQLException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:704)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:358)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:454)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
```

What did I config wrong in the Realm file? Why do I get this message?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Put the necessary JDBC libraries (e.g. classes12.jar) in the `tomcat/lib` directory.